# Sharepoint 2010 - when someone approves a document - enterprise keywords are removed (or hidden)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Enterprise Keywords have started to "disappear" from the view properties page on documents in certain folders - not all folders yet...

I have tried /Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx permissions - this hasn't fixed the issue

If I update a document myself - it does add the enterprise keywords - but the document is set as pending, once you approve it - the keywords disappear

Can someone help here please?